# How to use nested data in kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, kibana, elastic-stack

I'm trying to work out how to convert essentially relational data into a document format for use in kibana searches / visualisations.

I think I need my document to look like this:

```
{
    "order": {
        "id": 123,
        "customer": "bob",
        "email": "robert@bob.com",
        "items": [{
                "id": "xyz",
                "price": 12.2
            }, {
                "id": "abc",
                "price": 13.1
            },
            {
                "id": "abc",
                "price": 13.1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Where I don't know how many items I'll have for each order, hence needing this to be some sort of nested document structure.

I can get this all into Elastic happily and set my type to be nested.

But I'm not seeing how I can answer questions in Kibana like:

1. What is the total price of the items in the order (38.4)
2. What are the different totals of all the items (xyz=1,abc=2)

I've tried looking at various blogs, SO questions etc but not finding what I need, which means I'm probably thinking about this wrong.

The only answer I can come up with which I'm trying to avoid is that my document needs to calculate the answers to the questions when they're sent in so they can be searched on as standard fields.

Any pointers on what I should be reading up on?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (very long) aggregation below should answer both your questions:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "nested_items": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "items"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_document": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "_id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "group_by_item_id": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "items.id"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "total_price_by_item_id": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "items.price"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "total_price_by_document": {
              "sum_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "group_by_item_id>total_price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In plain words:

1. `nested_items` enables aggregating the nested `items` field (see [nested aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-aggregations-bucket-nested-aggregation.html))
2. `group_by_document`, well, groups by documents using the `_id` field
3. `group_by_item_id` groups the `items` by their id
4. `total_price_by_item_id` sums the prices of all the items with a given `items.id` of a certain document
5. `total_price_by_document` sums the sums of prices by `items.id` (see [pipeline aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-aggregations-pipeline.html)

Comment: Unless I've missed the point of how elastic and kibana link together, how can I use the above aggregation in a visualisations (e.g. pie chart)?

Comment: It's not supported in Kibana currently:
https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/1084